# How to have Keras LSTM make predictions for multiple time-series in a multivariate setting?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to use Keras to make simultaneous predictions for multiple variables. Using [this example here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/), I want to predict values for all features including pm 2.5, DEWP, TEMP etc. instead of just pollution (pm 2.5). Essentially, this is, given all the variables, build a model to predict all variables as time series, not just forecasting one variable.

I modified the original sample code by using the reshaped 3D data, but got an error. Here's the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense


from math import sqrt
from numpy import concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat


from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame, concat
from datetime import datetime
# load data
def parse(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H')
dataset = read_csv('raw.csv',  parse_dates = [['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']], index_col=0, date_parser=parse)
dataset.drop('No', axis=1, inplace=True)
# manually specify column names
dataset.columns = ['pollution', 'dew', 'temp', 'press', 'wnd_dir', 'wnd_spd', 'snow', 'rain']
dataset.index.name = 'date'
# mark all NA values with 0
dataset['pollution'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
# drop the first 24 hours
dataset = dataset[24:]
# summarize first 5 rows
print(dataset.head(5))
# save to file
dataset.to_csv('pollution.csv')


# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg


# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:,4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)


# split into train and test sets
values = reframed.values
n_train_hours = 365 * 24
train = values[:n_train_hours, :]
test = values[n_train_hours:, :]
# split into input and outputs
train_X, train_y = train[:, :-8], train[:, -8:]
test_X, test_y = test[:, :-8], test[:, -8:]
# reshape input to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]
train_X_3d = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X_3d = test_X.reshape((test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))
train_y_3d = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], 1, train_y.shape[1]))
test_y_3d = test_y.reshape((test_y.shape[0], 1, test_y.shape[1]))
print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape, test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
print(train_X_3d.shape, train_y_3d.shape, test_X_3d.shape, test_y_3d.shape)

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X_3d.shape[1], train_X_3d.shape[2])))
#model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X_3d, train_y_3d, 
                    epochs=50, batch_size=72, 
                    validation_data=(test_X_3d, test_y_3d), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

# make a prediction
yhat = model.predict(test_X_3d)
yhat
```

The output is:

```
                     pollution  dew  temp   press wnd_dir  wnd_spd  snow  rain
date                                                                          
2010-01-02 00:00:00      129.0  -16  -4.0  1020.0      SE     1.79     0     0
2010-01-02 01:00:00      148.0  -15  -4.0  1020.0      SE     2.68     0     0
2010-01-02 02:00:00      159.0  -11  -5.0  1021.0      SE     3.57     0     0
2010-01-02 03:00:00      181.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     5.36     1     0
2010-01-02 04:00:00      138.0   -7  -5.0  1022.0      SE     6.25     2     0
(8760, 8) (8760, 8) (35039, 8) (35039, 8)
(8760, 1, 8) (8760, 1, 8) (35039, 1, 8) (35039, 1, 8)
Train on 8760 samples, validate on 35039 samples
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1609   try:
-> 1610     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1611   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 50 and 8 for 'loss/lstm_loss/sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,50], [?,1,8].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-00c079ab5854> in <module>
     97 history = model.fit(train_X_3d, train_y_3d, 
     98                     epochs=50, batch_size=72,
---> 99                     validation_data=(test_X_3d, test_y_3d), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    100 # plot history
    101 pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    501       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    502       initializer_map = object_identity.ObjectIdentityDictionary()
--> 503       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
    504     finally:
    505       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    406     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    407         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 408             *args, **kwds))
    409 
    410     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1846     if self.input_signature:
   1847       args, kwargs = None, None
-> 1848     graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   1849     return graph_function
   1850 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2148         graph_function = self._function_cache.primary.get(cache_key, None)
   2149         if graph_function is None:
-> 2150           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2151           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2152         return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2039             arg_names=arg_names,
   2040             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2041             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2042         self._function_attributes,
   2043         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    913                                           converted_func)
    914 
--> 915       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    916 
    917       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    356         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    357         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 358         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    359     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    360 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in distributed_function(input_iterator)
     71     strategy = distribution_strategy_context.get_strategy()
     72     outputs = strategy.experimental_run_v2(
---> 73         per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))
     74     # Out of PerReplica outputs reduce or pick values to return.
     75     all_outputs = dist_utils.unwrap_output_dict(

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in experimental_run_v2(self, fn, args, kwargs)
    758       fn = autograph.tf_convert(fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx(),
    759                                 convert_by_default=False)
--> 760       return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    761 
    762   def reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   1785       kwargs = {}
   1786     with self._container_strategy().scope():
-> 1787       return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
   1788 
   1789   def _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in _call_for_each_replica(self, fn, args, kwargs)
   2130         self._container_strategy(),
   2131         replica_id_in_sync_group=constant_op.constant(0, dtypes.int32)):
-> 2132       return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2133 
   2134   def _reduce_to(self, reduce_op, value, destinations):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    290   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    291     with ag_ctx.ControlStatusCtx(status=ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED):
--> 292       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    293 
    294   if inspect.isfunction(func) or inspect.ismethod(func):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in train_on_batch(model, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
    262       y,
    263       sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 264       output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)
    265 
    266   if reset_metrics:

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in train_on_batch(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, output_loss_metrics)
    309           sample_weights=sample_weights,
    310           training=True,
--> 311           output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics))
    312   if not isinstance(outs, list):
    313     outs = [outs]

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _process_single_batch(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    250               output_loss_metrics=output_loss_metrics,
    251               sample_weights=sample_weights,
--> 252               training=training))
    253       if total_loss is None:
    254         raise ValueError('The model cannot be run '

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_eager.py in _model_loss(model, inputs, targets, output_loss_metrics, sample_weights, training)
    164 
    165         if hasattr(loss_fn, 'reduction'):
--> 166           per_sample_losses = loss_fn.call(targets[i], outs[i])
    167           weighted_losses = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    168               per_sample_losses,

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
    219       y_pred, y_true = tf_losses_util.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
    220           y_pred, y_true)
--> 221     return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    222 
    223   def get_config(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/losses.py in mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
    781   y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    782   y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
--> 783   return K.mean(math_ops.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
    784 
    785 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in binary_op_wrapper(x, y)
    897     with ops.name_scope(None, op_name, [x, y]) as name:
    898       if isinstance(x, ops.Tensor) and isinstance(y, ops.Tensor):
--> 899         return func(x, y, name=name)
    900       elif not isinstance(y, sparse_tensor.SparseTensor):
    901         try:

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py in sub(x, y, name)
  11086   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  11087   _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
> 11088         "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  11089   _result = _op.outputs[:]
  11090   _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    791         op = g.create_op(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None, name=scope,
    792                          input_types=input_types, attrs=attr_protos,
--> 793                          op_def=op_def)
    794       return output_structure, op_def.is_stateful, op
    795 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py in create_op(***failed resolving arguments***)
    546     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    547         op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def,
--> 548         compute_device)
    549 
    550   def capture(self, tensor, name=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3427           input_types=input_types,
   3428           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3429           op_def=op_def)
   3430       self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_device=compute_device)
   3431     return ret

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   1771           op_def, inputs, node_def.attr)
   1772       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, grouped_inputs,
-> 1773                                 control_input_ops)
   1774     # pylint: enable=protected-access
   1775 

~/anaconda3/envs/topic_forecaster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1611   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1612     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1613     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1614 
   1615   return c_op

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 50 and 8 for 'loss/lstm_loss/sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,50], [?,1,8].
```

The dataset is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pollution.csv).

My questions are:

- Is the Keras LSTM layer not designed for this? Maybe it's only for one time-series?
- If LSTM is good, what can be a good fix?
- If LSTM is not good, what other methods should I use if I want to model both the interaction between the features and also make predictions for all features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) (under "Multiple Parallel Series"). We just need to reshape the features and labels and feed in the network, it'll just work! The features should have the shape of (n_steps, n_features) while the labels should have the shape (n_samples, n_features) (if we are predicting 1 timestep).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense


from math import sqrt
from numpy import array, concatenate
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat


from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame, concat
from datetime import datetime
# load data
def parse(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H')
dataset = read_csv('raw.csv',  parse_dates = [['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']], index_col=0, date_parser=parse)
dataset.drop('No', axis=1, inplace=True)
# manually specify column names
dataset.columns = ['pollution', 'dew', 'temp', 'press', 'wnd_dir', 'wnd_spd', 'snow', 'rain']
dataset.index.name = 'date'
# mark all NA values with 0
dataset['pollution'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
# drop the first 24 hours
dataset = dataset[24:]
# summarize first 5 rows
print(dataset.head(5))
# save to file
dataset.to_csv('pollution.csv')


# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:,4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)

n_steps = 10
n_features = 8

def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if end_ix > len(sequences)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix, :]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

X, y = split_sequences(sequences=scaled, n_steps=n_steps)
print(X.shape, y.shape)

X = X[:1000, :]
y = y[:1000, :]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=False, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
#model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_features))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')


# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose=1)
# demonstrate prediction
x_input = X[0]
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```